# Heroku two-factor authentication multiple devices?

Tags: heroku, two-factor-authentication

How can I set up two-factor authentication on Heroku with more than one device?

My business partner & I both need access to the account.

Comment: Why not just create organization account and have two admin users?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set up 2FA on multiple devices, you should scan the same QR code by both devices (yours and your business partner’s) at the moment of token enrollment. As a result, the server and your devices have the same secret key and based on it they generate the same OTPs. Once it will be done, both your partner and you have an access to your Heroku account.